# Signature with HMAC SHA-256 and Base64Encoder

Tags: java, ruby, base64, digital-signature, hmac

I tried a lot for creating signature to access one web service.

They required that I generate a signature with each request.

For generating signature, I have one message say "abc" and one secrete key say "xyz".  According to them my signature should be processed as the following ruby code

```
require 'base64'

require 'openssl'

secret = "xyz"

request = "abc"

digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha256')

signature = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, secret, request)).chomp
```

`signature` should be `9ZjsfVB3k5nPNLf5he+gfyYaxNWCIJ6J8YcRpxW5GG0=` but I am not getting this using Java code which is as below:

```
 SecretKey secretKey = null;    

 byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");     

 Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HMACHSA256");

 secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,mac.getAlgorithm());

 mac.init(secretKey);   

 byte[] text = baseString.getBytes("UTF-8");

 //mac.update(digest.digest());

 byte[] encodedText = mac.doFinal(text);    

 return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encodedText)).trim();
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: is *"HMACHSA256"* a typo?  Is it actual running code that you pasted?  Shouldn't that String be, for a start, "*HMACSHA256"*?

Comment: yes this is my running code and i am getting signature but its not correct signature.

Comment: @user1141515: Funny, you should get a `NoSuchAlgorithmException` - I also think you meant to type "HMACSHA256" above.

Comment: I have done a little PHP before.  I have done no Ruby.  But this is Ruby, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the Java code and got `oQLjGtDh255Vg5ix4fjVzHvFOq7TNygJRcbQ/EnF8JE=`

I went to [this](http://www.online-convert.com/result/7db14d1a4f32b7738b727d8a58783b18) online site and I got `oQLjGtDh255Vg5ix4fjVzHvFOq7TNygJRcbQ/EnF8JE=`

I ran the top script as a **ruby** script, and I got `oQLjGtDh255Vg5ix4fjVzHvFOq7TNygJRcbQ/EnF8JE=`

Since those three match, I suggest that all the code above is consistent but the value you report is not correct.  The above Java code is pretty much textbook HMACSHA256 for Java but I cannot comment on the Ruby part because I am only a Java guy.